# Adding Tables to dataset by multiple threads is thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, dataset, parallel.foreach

Is 
Adding Tables to dataset by multiple threads is thread safe?

```
    List<Action> TestActions = new List<Action>();

    Action action1 = new Action(() => Method1(dsDataset));
    TestActions.Add(action1);

    Action action2 = new Action(() => Method2(dsDataset));
    TestActions.Add(action2);

    Action action3 = new Action(() => Method3(dsDataset));
    TestActions.Add(action3);

    try
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(TestActions, (a) => a());
    }

    Method1(DataSet ds) {
    //excecute a db call and returns  datatable
    Datatable db ={database query}
    ds.Tables.Add(db)
    }
            Method2(DataSet ds) {
    //excecute a db call and returns  datatable
    Datatable db ={database query}
    ds.Tables.Add(db)
    }
            Method3(DataSet ds) {
    //excecute a db call and returns  datatable
    Datatable db ={database query}
    ds.Tables.Add(db)
    }
```

Is the Above code works or i need to lock put the lock on the dataset when each thread tries to add?
Is there any better way i can do?

Answer (score 0):

From [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablecollection(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must synchronize any write operations.

So, the answer is: no, it is not safe. Use synchrinisation or add tables in a single thread.
Just curious, why do you need to do it in parallel?

If it is because of some work that have to be done in parallel and as result of this work you need to add a table into ds, I can recoment use of one [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) to store tables and one worker thread that will pick items from that queue and add them to a ds.